# How to assign random values for each gameobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey i'm just a beginner in unity. I need to assign a random value for the int (coconut1iD,coconut2iD, etc...) of each gameobject in unity.
All of those int gets the same value.
i am doing something wrong here.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class randomvaluegenerator: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject coconut1;
    public GameObject coconut2;
    public GameObject coconut3;
    public GameObject coconut4;

    int Rand;
    int Lenght = 5;
    List < int > list = new List < int > ();

    void Start()
    {
        list = new List < int > (new int[Lenght]);

        for (int i = 1; i < Lenght; i++) 
        {
            Rand = Random.Range(1, 5);

            while (list.Contains(Rand))
            {
                Rand = Random.Range(1, 5);
            }

            list[i] = Rand;

            coconut1.GetComponent < coconut1id > ().coconut1iD = list[i];
            coconut2.GetComponent < coconut2id > ().coconut2iD = list[i];
            coconut3.GetComponent < coconut3id > ().coconut3iD = list[i];
            coconut4.GetComponent < coconut4id > ().coconut4iD = list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are setting all the variables to the same value.

```
coconut1.GetComponent < coconut1id > ().coconut1iD = list[i];
coconut2.GetComponent < coconut2id > ().coconut2iD = list[i];
coconut3.GetComponent < coconut3id > ().coconut3iD = list[i];
coconut4.GetComponent < coconut4id > ().coconut4iD = list[i];
```

which is wrong, what you should do is get all the random numbers and then set each component to a value in the list of random numbers

```
void Start()
    {
        list = new List < int > (new int[Lenght]);

        for (int i = 1; i < Lenght; i++) 
        {
            Rand = Random.Range(1, 5);

            while (list.Contains(Rand))
            {
                Rand = Random.Range(1, 5);
            }

            list[i] = Rand;
        }

        coconut1.GetComponent < coconut1id > ().coconut1iD = list[1];
        coconut2.GetComponent < coconut2id > ().coconut2iD = list[2];
        coconut3.GetComponent < coconut3id > ().coconut3iD = list[3];
        coconut4.GetComponent < coconut4id > ().coconut4iD = list[4];
    }
```

Comment: it's just not random. it's in a order like 2, 3, 4 etc...

Comment: it's working correct after the edit i made

Answer (score 0):

This is the working script. Thanks wale A.

```
using System.Collections;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using UnityEngine;    
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class randomvaluegenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject coconut1;

    public GameObject coconut2;

    public GameObject coconut3;

    public GameObject coconut4;

    int Rand;

    int Lenght = 5;

    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    void Start()
    {
        list = new List<int>(new int[Lenght]);

        for (int i = 1; i < Lenght; i++)
        {
            Rand = Random.Range(1, 5);

            while (list.Contains(Rand))
            {
                Rand = Random.Range(1, 5);
            }

            list[i] = Rand;
        }

        coconut1.GetComponent<coconut1id>().coconut1iD = list[1];
        coconut2.GetComponent<coconut2id>().coconut2iD = list[2];
        coconut3.GetComponent<coconut3id>().coconut3iD = list[3];
        coconut4.GetComponent<coconut4id>().coconut4iD = list[4];
    }
}
```